# Not able to load tesseract.js on my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cdn, tesseract.js

I am trying to make a chrome extension that takes screenshots and the idea is to pass it through tesseract.js

But while I am using CDN script tag

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.1.0/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
```

I am getting this error:
[error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf9gl.jpg)

> Refused to load the script 'https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.1.0/dist/tesseract.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Any suggestion what I need to do?
I dont want to use npm method.

Do I need to add `content_security_policy` to my manifest.json file? If Yes, then what?

Answer (score 0):

[Refer the screenshot from manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/806Ym.png)

You can use the tesseract.min.js file as the content script in manifest.json. Now, perform the Tesseract related tasks in the separate content.js file which is invoked on click of the button in popup.html.

Since we are using tesseract file as the content script hence the tesseract variables are available for the invoked content script and hence we can successfully perform all the tesseract related operations in this file.